# When I call mysql function DBMS returns error 1366 incorrect string value

Tags: mysql, function

I have a small application that is written in JavaFx that I use to keep track off all the students. Until few days ago everything was fine but for some reason a problem occurred.

I use XAMPP with mysql database. In this database I have table called students

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `id_st` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `lName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `st_index` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `createdOn` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_st`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=574 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I hava a function

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `checkIfStudentIsAddedToStudents`(_fName VARCHAR(30), _lName VARCHAR(30), _email VARCHAR(40)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN

    declare id_STUDENT INTEGER;

    select ifnull(id_st,0) into id_STUDENT from student where fname = _fName AND lName = _LName AND email = _email;

RETURN id_STUDENT;
END//
```

For some reason when I call a function with parameters it returns an error 1366 incorrect string value, but when I just call a select that is inside this function everything works.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you try to repair your table?

Comment: This is oftentimes an encoding problem (e.g. you may send utf16 instead of utf8 or something like this). Check if you did something a few days ago that might (unintentionally) cause "for some reason" to occur (changing java/php, linux, connector library or mysql version, editing config files, recovering from backup, ...)

Comment: Well I did not change any encoding on tables. However I have moved my DB from MySQL to MariaDB (export/import).

Comment: I have added a log function to my checkIfStudentIsAddedToStudents function and I have found out that characters ć č đ ž are not read correctly when passed as parameters. Any suggestion?